# Как следует расставить знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

**Изменил тело вопроса: заменил союз "а" на "и", т. к. именно в знаках препинания между союзами (любыми) суть того, в чем я пытаюсь разобраться.  Nektoid ответил на вопрос в начальном его виде, за что ему спасибо.**

*И вот если он никакого сообщения в ближайшие дни не оставит − можно волноваться.*
*И, если он никакого сообщения в ближайшие дни не оставит, − можно волноваться.*

Мои мысли:

Во втором случае у нас встреча двух союзов, надо бы их разделить запятой, т.к. нет во второй части предложения еще одного союза (хотя он подразумевается, но заменен тире − в этом еще одна проблема). Правильно? Выходит, тире здесь − только вспомогательный знак, а не полноценная замена "то".

В первом предложении "вот" создает тесную связь между союзами; как (и зачем) их разделять − мне неясно.

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, верно ли я размышляю, правильно ли расставлены в предложениях знаки препинания.

Comment: Та же петрушка.

Comment: Вы правы в своих рассуждениях: тире не замена 'то', а интонационный необязательный знак. Сочетание 'И вот если', судя по примерам из нацкорпуса, делится запятой или не делится не из-за последующей частицы 'то', а оттого, нужно ли автору отделить 'если' от 'и вот' или не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

**А если он никакого сообщения в ближайшие дни не оставит, можно волноваться.**
Либо:
**А если он никакого сообщения в ближайшие дни не оставит − можно волноваться.**

Розенталь (Пунктуация, § 36.5 п. 2):

> После присоединительного союза "а" [перед следующим за ним подчинительным союзом] запятая не ставится: *А когда
> взошло солнце, перед нами открылся вид на снеговую вершину; А если
> верить сообщениям синоптиков, завтра должно наступить потепление*.

То есть наличие/отсутствие коррелята "то" не влияет на непостановку запятой между "а" и подчинительным союзом.